How to troubleshoot XPath not finding elements on a web page?
I am using a Bash script to search a web page with a specific XPath expression:

# Define variables for the URL and browser
sGDomain="idealista"
sGCitta="fucecchio-firenze"
sGTypo="vendita-case"
iGPagina=1

# Start of the loop
while :; do

    # Build the URL with the iGPagina variable
    url="https://www.$sGDomain.it/$sGTypo/$sGCitta/lista-$iGPagina.htm"
    #echo "$url"
    
    # Get the HTML content of the page
    html_content=$(curl -s -L -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0" "$url")

    echo "$html_content" > htmlcompleto.txt
    
    # Check if the error string is not present in the HTML content
    if [[ ! $html_content =~ "Successiva" ]]; then
        break  # Exit the loop if the error string is not present
    fi
    
    # Use xidel to extract the ads
    xidel_output=$(xidel --silent --xpath '
        //div[contains(@class, "item-info-container")] ! string-join(
            (
                ( "price=" || normalize-space(.//span[contains(@class, "item-price")]/text()[1]) ),
                ( "size="  || normalize-space(.//span[contains(@class, "item-detail") and contains(text(), "m2")]) ),
                ( "link="  || normalize-space(.//a[contains(@class, "item-link")]/@href) ),
                ( "desc="  || normalize-space(.//p[contains(@class, "ellipsis")]) )
            ),
            codepoints-to-string(9)
        )
    ' -)

    # Check if the temporary file exists and delete it if present
    if [ -f "temp.txt" ]; then
        rm temp.txt
    fi

    # Replace special characters from "desc=" to the end of each line in semi.txt
    echo "$xidel_output" | sed -e "s/desc=\(.*\)\(['\"]\)/desc=\1 /g" > semi.txt

    sed -i 's/\([0-9]\{1,\}\)\.\([0-9]\{1,\}\),[0-9]\{2\}/\1\2/g' semi.txt
    sed -i 's/m²//g' semi.txt

    # Concatenate semi.txt with debugtxt.txt for debugging purposes
    cat semi.txt >> debugtxt.txt

    # Connect to the SQLite database
    db_file="immo.db"
 
    # Loop through the lines and insert them into the SQLite database
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        # Extract price, size, link, and description values from the lines using awk
        prezzo=$(echo "$line" | awk -F 'price=' '{print $2}' | awk -F 'size=' '{print $1}')
        size=$(echo "$line" | awk -F 'size=' '{print $2}' | awk -F 'link=' '{print $1}')
        link=$(echo "$line" | awk -F 'link=' '{print $2}' | awk -F 'desc=' '{print $1}')
        descrizione=$(echo "$line" | awk -F 'desc=' '{print $2}')

        # Determine if the description contains "asta"
        if [[ $descrizione =~ "asta" ]]; then
            asta=1
        else
            asta=0
        fi

        # Insert the data into the SQLite database
        sqlite3 "$db_file" "INSERT INTO $sGDomain (prezzo, link, descrizione, metratura, asta) VALUES ('$prezzo', '$link', '$descrizione', '$size', $asta)"
    done < semi.txt

    # Increment the iGPagina variable for the next iteration**your text**
    ((iGPagina++))
done

Although I believe the XPath is correct, the script fails to find anything on the page.
Web page URL: https://www.idealista.it/vendita-case/fucecchio-firenze/lista-18.htm.
XPath expression used:
//div[contains(@class, "item-info-container")] ! string-join(
  (
    ( "price=" || normalize-space(.//span[contains(@class, "item-price")]/text()[1]) ),
    ( "size="  || normalize-space(.//span[contains(@class, "item-detail") and contains(text(), "m2")]) ),
    ( "link="  || normalize-space(.//a[contains(@class, "item-link")]/@href) ),
    ( "desc="  || normalize-space(.//p[contains(@class, "ellipsis")]) )
  ),
  codepoints-to-string(9)
)

I also tried this XPath expression with //div[contains(@class, "items-container items-list")], but it didn't work either.
Expected result: I expect to extract the price, the listing link, the description, and the square meters from each listing on the web page.

There was a very similar question with a very similar script, but asked by someone else (now deleted).

yes I remember I copied the script and adapted it for my use but not being an xpath expert I may have made some mistakes therefore i ask

For debugging this, just the xidel command into a script on its own, without any shell variables in it. Once this works, we can go on further from this.

xidel i suppose  work,but the problem i suppose is match in correct way the part in webpage

Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/a/78583954/3387716 for a more robust way to link xidel output to sqlite3 import?

@Fravadona, sorry if i disturb, suppose you use another  site i used  this https://www.subito.it/annunci-toscana/vendita/immobili/firenze/fucecchio/?order=priceasc&o=1 , in this case i can take  all data  but link no "link="  || normalize-space(.//a[contains(@class, "BigCard-module_link__kVqPE")]/@href), i notice curl not take all data and use wget that work much better,but xpath not take link why ?

So the essence of your question, your script, comes down to; how can I execute several sqlite3-commands with information extracted from a particular website.
I have no experience with sqlite3, so I can't comment on @Fravadona's JSON solution, but I do know xidel. If you ask me, I think your best bet would be to let xidel create the sqlite3-commands as strings, which you can then execute afterwards. In the process there's no need for curl, awk, etc. Make sure you're using the latest (development) build of xidel though.
$ xidel -s \
  --user-agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0" \
  "https://www.idealista.it/vendita-case/fucecchio-firenze/lista-1.htm" \
  -e '
    for $x in //div[contains-token(@class,"item-info-container")]
    let $a:=$x/div[contains-token(@class,"item-description")]/normalize-space(p[@class="ellipsis"])
    return
    $x/`sqlite3 "immo.db" "INSERT INTO idealista (prezzo, link, descrizione, metratura, asta) VALUES ('\''{
      div[@class="price-row"]/span[contains-token(@class,"item-price")]/text()
    }'\'', '\''{
      a[@class="item-link "]/resolve-uri(@href)
    }'\'', '\''{
      $a
    }'\'', '\''{
      tokenize(div[@class="item-detail-char"]/span[contains(text(),"m2")])[1]
    }'\'', '\''{
      if (matches($a,"asta")) then 1 else 0
    }'\'')"`
  ' \
  -f '//li[@class="next"]/a/@href' \
  2>/dev/null


I've tested several other more recent user-agent strings, but so far only the one you provided worked. Very peculiar.
Put the description in a variable ($a) to check later on if it contains "asta" or not. If "ASTA", or "Asta" is also acceptable, then you can use contains() instead of matches().
The string concatenation expression used here is an XPath 4.0 String Template.
-f (or --follow) before an extraction-query 'follows' / opens the queried url just once. After an extraction-query it works recursively. In other words, in this case xidel opens 'lista-1.htm', executes the extraction-query, opens 'lista-2.htm', again executes the extraction-query, opens 'lista-3.htm', etc.
2>/dev/null is to silence the message "!!! Recursive follow is deprecated and might be removed soon. !!!" This has come up almost 3 years ago, but so far the feature is still present.
See this gist for intermediate steps.

Instead of the XPath 4.0 String Templates, you could also use good old concat():
$ xidel -s \
  --user-agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0" \
  "https://www.idealista.it/vendita-case/fucecchio-firenze/lista-1.htm" \
  -e '
    for $x in //div[contains-token(@class,"item-info-container")]
    let $a:=$x/div[contains-token(@class,"item-description")]/normalize-space(p[@class="ellipsis"])
    return
    $x/concat(
      "sqlite3 ""immo.db"" ""INSERT INTO idealista (prezzo, link, descrizione, metratura, asta) VALUES ('\''",
      div[@class="price-row"]/span[contains-token(@class,"item-price")]/text(),
      "'\'', '\''",
      a[@class="item-link "]/resolve-uri(@href),
      "'\'', '\''",
      $a,
      "'\'', '\''",
      tokenize(div[@class="item-detail-char"]/span[contains(text(),"m2")])[1],
      "'\'', '\''",
      if (matches($a,"asta")) then 1 else 0,
      "'\'')"""
    )
  ' \
  -f '//li[@class="next"]/a/@href' \
  2>/dev/null

And finally you could then probably just execute these sqlite3-commands by putting eval "$( ... )" around the entire xidel-command.

woow  I still don't know how you manage to do all this but you are definitely TOP thank you

I ran your first xidel, which output nothing. Is this expected ?

@Philippe Are you using the latest xidel build, as I pointed out? See here, or here.

@eofficecomcom If you find my answer helpful, then please read "What should I do when someone answers my question?".

Thank you very much for pointing out! I do have the latest official version (0.9.8), but not the latest build (0.9.9).
